# Check localStorage if item matches string

Tags: javascript, local-storage, match

I want to proof if an item exists in localStorage, where the itemID matches a string, to remove it. The clear function works fine, but not without removing everything. Is there any way to do it?

```
    var myMatch = "test";
    localStorage.setItem("test_1", "value");

    -> localStorage.getItem(); // ?
```

Comment: There is no `get` method. Did you mean `getItem`? Then remove it with `removeItem`.

Comment: Sorry I mean getItem() ;)

Comment: @CoderofCode it is not duplicate at all. Please have a look at question again. `get()` and `getItem()` just a typo as per last comment of DataCent

Comment: Can you please clarify your needs in an [edit] to your question? It is unclear if you want to check for a perfect match (as in check if `localStorage[myMatch]` is set) where it would make little sense since you could just try to remove it otherwise, or if you want to remove all the keys that do match a pattern like `contains(myMatch)`.

Answer (score 1):

`localstorage` has function `getItem()` instead of `get()`.

So change:

```
localStorage.get(itemID);
```

To:

```
localStorage.getItem(itemID);
```

So your final code will be like below:

```
  var myMatch = "test";

  if (localStorage.getItem(itemID) === myMatch) {
    localStorage.removeItem(itemID)
  }
```

For more information in `localStorage` please check [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Storage).

Comment: Thanks but what's if I don't know the itemID ??? it's created automaticly from only DB

Comment: @DataCent Actually it depends upon your code and logic,. You don't need to know `itemID` if there is single `itemID` and you want to remove that only but if you have multiple `itemID` then while removing you must need to know specific `itemID` which you want to remove. Hope this will clear your doubt.

Comment: @Kaiido thanks for the information, I didn't know. Will update my answer.

Comment: @VicJordan but is possible to get all localStorage IDs without knowing them, so that i can match after that?

Comment: @DataCent yes you can pull all the items using `var items = {...localStorage};`

Comment: Had a typo so I rewrite: @DataCent you can do `Object.keys(localStorage)`, with the known issues of `getItem`, `setItem`, `length`, etc. for which you'd have to do `getItem(key) !== null`. So the full code would be `Object.keys(localStorage).concat(['key', 'clear', 'removeItem', 'getItem', 'setItem', 'length'].filter(k=>localStorage.getItem(k)!==null))`.

Comment: @Kaiido I just updated the answer as per the requirement. Please have a look.

Comment: Nope, won't work for [the keys I mentioned](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52157909/check-localstorage-if-item-matches-string/52157920?noredirect=1#comment91266311_52157920). And your first revision was a better answer to this question. If OP wants something else, they should post an other question cc @DataCent

Comment: @Kaiido Thank you for the information. I got your point and agree with you as well. If there will be something else requirement then OP can post a separate question.

Comment: @Kaiido I have revised it. Just in if you haven't upvoted my answer then please do so. thank you :)

Comment: Actually wait a minute *I* may have misread the question (which is anyway unclear as it is IMM) Do they want to find the jeys that do match a pattern like `^myMatch`? In this case none of your revs really answer that.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/179347/discussion-between-vicjordan-and-kaiido).